# How do i put only the first string of a line in an array while using console.readline

Tags: arrays, console.readline

I need to only get the first Numbers of an input line from the console.
If the console gives input being:

```
20 //this is some input text
```

Then I need my array to be only filled with the number 20 while still using console.readline.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing maybe you're working in C#???

Try this:

```
var line = "20 //this is some input text";
var num = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' ')));
```

Then use the variable num for whatever you want.  You can put it in an array like you want.